# How to export data from SQL without using the import/export wizard?

Tags: sql-server, excel, csv, export, ssms

I need to export data from SQL to csv or Excel without using the wizard. It must be done through query. I looked a lot online, but could not find a solution. The best solution I found was to use a command code to export the data, but this returns the data without headers. Please help !

Edit:
I am new to SQL, and really been researching this for a while. I therefore would be grateful if you can give me the code to do this in SQL management studio (if possible). Many thanks !!!

Comment: Which dbms are you using? ANSI/ISO SQL has no export functionality.

Comment: I am using SQL server 2014 management studio

Comment: Have a look at the `sqlcmd` tool, described here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773(v=sql.120).aspx

Comment: I did, didn’t help! The most I could do is use cmd to export the data, but it does not have the column names !

Answer (score 0):

Rather than pushing the data out from SQL Management Studio, you could create a connection to the database within Excel and pull the data in.

In Excel, choose `Data > From Other Sources > From SQL Server` (or `Data > New Query > From Database > From SQL Database`)

Select the database, database table etc.

If you need to filter or otherwise manipulate the data rather than pull in the whole table, then you can go to the `Connection Properties` dialog afterwards and enter whatever SQL you want into the `Definition` tab. For instance `select * from <table> where <field> = "value"`.

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful. But is there no way of writing a script that does it on SQL?